# What is this pipe with wires in my new house side yard

Tags: wiring, pipe, new-home, sidewalk

Not sure what it is. Its a pvc pipe about 1ft high and some wires wrapped around it. Its in my side yard. Any idea what it is before I ask my builder about it?

[image: pic]

Comment: Looks like the wires could be for irrigation valves.  Are you having an Irrigation system installed< or ask for an irrigation stub-out?

Comment: Yes I have irrigation installed. 2 station in front. So is that a point provided to extend irrigation in back/side yard?

Comment: Very possible. The wire is typical for irrigation use.  The pipe may be a water source.  Verify with the builder.

Comment: Thanks a lot RMDman. Will ask builder too on how how can I leverage it for my diy back and side yard.

Comment: Frankly, asking the builder should be option #1 in this situation. (S)he will _know_ while the internet will only be able to give you _guesses_.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ready made provision for irrigation valves.

Look in your irrigation panel if it has cables going out.

The trick would be in matching colors.